# Octopus gem dynamically select shard for an associated model based on shard_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sharding, octopus

We have a users table.  Users have many listings.

We'd like to shard the association model Listing such that all users stay on database "master" shard.  Users will get a shard_id column and listings will be split into different databases "shard1", "shard2".

We can augment our code to access the listings on the correct shard using the `using` method:

```
Listing.where(user: current_user).using(current_user.shard_id)
```

However that is a big code change.  Ideally we want to just keep using our existing association statements like this:

```
current_user.listings
```

And have it automatically use `current_user.shard_id` beneath the hood.

Any suggestions for doing this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this when using associations on different shards without needing to update each and every use of the chained association in the code base?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `current_user.listings` should work out of the box.

> Octopus also handles associations. When you try to get a object that is associated to another object, you could use normal ActiveRecord syntax to get the objects

https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/wiki/How-Octopus-Works

Comment: That only works if current_user and listings are on the same shard.  It doesn't work if User is on master shard and Listing is on Shard1.  current_user will assume the association is on the same shard as the current_user.